# Selecting Cells in Pandas MultiIndex DataFrames Using a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to set the values of certain cells in a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame by selecting these cells using a list.

*Note the sequence of both lists.*

```
df.loc[(['Peter','John','Tom'],'AAPL'),1] = ['Peter', 'John', 'Tom']
```

**Problem:** However, the values are being set to the wrong cell. For example, I expect the value `Peter` to be set under the index `Peter`, but it is being set under `Tom`!

Anyone knows the reason, and what the proper way of doing this is?

In other words, how do we ensure the sequence of the list used in `df.loc()` (eg: `['Peter','John','Tom']` inside `df.loc`) to be the same sequence as the list of values (eg: `['Peter','John','Tom']` to the right of `=`)

**Expected Result**

```
             0      1   2
Name  Stock              
Tom   AAPL   0    Tom   0
      GOOG   0      0   0
      NFLX   0      0   0
John  AAPL   0   John   0
      GOOG   0      0   0
      NFLX   0      0   0
Peter AAPL   0  Peter   0
      GOOG   0      0  46
      NFLX   0      0   0
```

**Actual Result**

```
             0      1   2
Name  Stock              
Tom   AAPL   0  Peter   0   <----- should be Tom
      GOOG   0      0   0
      NFLX   0      0   0
John  AAPL   0   John   0
      GOOG   0      0   0
      NFLX   0      0   0
Peter AAPL   0    Tom   0   <----- should be Peter
      GOOG   0      0  46
      NFLX   0      0   0
```

**Code to reproduce problem**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Initialize MultiIndex DataFrame
stocks = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'NFLX']
names = ['Tom', 'John', 'Peter']
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([names, stocks], names=['Name','Stock'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=midx, columns=[0,1,2])
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:],:] = 0

# Partially populate the empty MultiIndex DataFrame
df.loc[('Tom', 'AAPL'), 1] = 36
df.loc[('Peter', 'GOOG'), 2] = 46
print(df)  # looks correct
```

```py
# Set values for some cells
df.loc[(['Peter','John','Tom'],'AAPL'),1] = ['Peter', 'John', 'Tom']
print(df)  # wrong!!!
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this, by giving the entire index for each elements.

```py
df.loc[[('Peter', 'AAPL'), ('John', 'AAPL'),('Tom','AAPL')],1] = ['Peter', 'John', 'Tom']
print(df)
```

[Fron pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

> Note It is important to note that tuples and lists are not treated identically in pandas when it comes to indexing. Whereas a tuple is interpreted as one multi-level key, a list is used to specify several keys. Or in other words, tuples go horizontally (traversing levels), lists go vertically (scanning levels).

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what is causing the issue, it can be stepped around by being more precise with the multiply indexed data.

```
df.loc[[('Peter','AAPL'),('John','AAPL'),('Tom','AAPL')],1] = ['Peter','John','Tom']
print(df) # this one works as you would expect

# to make it a bit more automated (create index from list, set 1st column to appropriate list item
# name list:
pjt = ['Peter','John','Tom']
# index list built from name list
pjt_aapl = [ (name,'AAPL') for name in ['Peter','John','Tom'] ]
# set first column to name
df.loc[ pjt_aapl, 1] = pjt
```

Cheers,
Jesse